# Files folder not opening Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: files, 23.04

I have Ubuntu 23.04 and today after the regular upgrade, I cannot open "Files" folder.
What all can I check, kindly advice.

Comment: Have you tried opening a terminal & running the command `nautilus` ?  as I'd expect the messages shown on terminal would provide the best clue (*and its easier than looking in logs in my opinion*). Next I'd probably look for anything in `/var/crash/`  (ie. maybe it's starting & crashing... evidence of that will be found in that directory).

Comment: Thanks, I actually followed a few recommendations in this forum and it was restored.